# which one to remove in a git merge conflict?

Tags: git, github

Whenever there's a git pull merge conflict, We often see something like this

```
<<<<<< HEAD 
some code snippet here

================

some code snippet here

adsf23423423423423 >>>>>>>>>
```

without looking at the ide history or git show or whatever history, and by just looking at the snippet that I posted, which one should we remove whenever there's a merge conflict?, is it the one inside the head? or the one at the bottom ?

(because there are times, that you didn't even touch the code that got conflict and you have no idea which one is the latest code from the developer who worked on it because you are too busy to look at the log history and compare)

Comment: If you always had to remove the top or bottom, Git would just do that itself. You have to understand the conflict and decide. The right answer might even involve changing more than just that section.

Comment: There's no hard and fast rule; the algorithm has failed and it's giving the decision making back to you. If you find this is happening a lot and you don't know why, you are probably integrating too infrequently and trying to work on the same code in parallel without communicating effectively.

Comment: If you're too busy to look at the log history, and/or speak to the developer(s) concerned, then you shouldn't be handling merge conflicts. And, as @jonrsharpe says, if this is happening too often you probably need to look at the way you work collaboratively.

Comment: actually before I asked this , it was already solved some days ago by asking the dev who was working on it. I was just wondering if there is a shortcut in doing the merge conflict fix without knowing what was conflicting

Comment: "a shortcut in doing the merge conflict fix without knowing what was conflicting" . . . seriously: step up your game, a _lot_, or find something else to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **code snippet** between the lines beginning <<<<<< and ================ here:

```
<<<<<< HEAD 
some code snippet here

================
```

... is what you already had locally - you can tell because HEAD points to your current branch or commit. The **code snippet** between the lines beginning ================ and >>>>>>>>>:

```
================

some code snippet here

adsf23423423423423 >>>>>>>>>
```

... is what was introduced by the other commit, in this case adsf23423423423423. That is the object name (or "hash", "SHA1sum", etc.) of the commit that was merged into HEAD. All objects in git, whether they're commits (version), blobs (files), trees (directories) or tags have such an object name, which identifies them uniquely based on their content.

You can now decide whether you want to keep the code snippet from HEAD or code snippet introduced by the  adsf23423423423423 commit.

If you are getting this merge conflicts from the code which you have never touched then keep the code introduced by the adsf23423423423423 commit.

Comment: well explained. thank you sir

Comment: "_keep the code snippet from HEAD or code snippet introduced by..._" **or** commit a "blend" of the two... a conflict basically means two _different_ sets of changes have been made to the same area of code. _Sometimes_ it is correct to take one or the other (e.g. one branch bumped a version number from 1.5 to 1.6; the other branch bumped it to 1.7) but often you'll need new code that takes into account _both_ sets of changes.

Answer (score 1):

It's a merge conflict because there isn't a consistent algorithm Git can use to decide which to take. You have context about what your code *does*, so you're in the best place to handle these edge cases that Git can't.

Fundamentally, a 'merge conflict' means that two different 'changes' were made concurrently, and they touched the same part of the codebase. This is an issue that requires the involvement of someone who knows what the code *does*. Git doesn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

Whichever one is outdated or wrong. Or maybe you'll have to manually merge them together, instead of keeping one and deleting the other.

Answer (score -1):

> <<<<<< HEAD

The beginning of the change in the HEAD (new-names) branch. In this case, HEAD represents the active branch into which you are merging.

> ================

The end of the change in the active or source branch (new-names) and the beginning of the change in the new names branch.

> adsf23423423423423 >>>>>>>>>

The end of the change in the destination (development branch).

But honestly, try to use a git merge tool like "git mergetool".

Hope it helps,